# Debugging Angular TFS extension

Tags: angular, tfs, azure-devops, vssdk

I used your example to create tfs extension with Angular and I deployed it successfully.
Now I would like to use the "baseUri" field in the vss-extension.json manifest to connect the extension to my server to debug the extension.

To do so I used ng serve --ssl to create a web server using https.
In the tfs, I can see that I make requests to my server and successfully get all the elements it required, but the extension itself failed to load and stuck on the "Loading" symbol with the title: "Extension is taking longer than expected to load".

No errors in the console and no 404 responses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if `VSS.init()` is missing in your html file.

`VSS.init()` is used to perform an initial handshake/setup with the host window.

[image]

In addition, We can provide options as input to this function, for example: we use `explicitNotifyLoaded: true,` to indicate that we will notify the host manually when the extension is done loading. This is used for the loading indicator. You can refer to this [blog](https://www.nocture.dk/2016/01/02/lets-make-a-visual-studio-team-services-extension/) for details.